# Compare std_logic_vector to a constant using std_logic_vector package ONLY

Tags: vhdl

I use the following package only in my VHDL file:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
```

In the code, I compare a std_logic_vector signal : A with a constant value, e.g

```
...if A<="00001011" then
```

yet the code was checked correctly by Xilinx ISE. My understanding is that STD_LOGIC_1164 package does not include an implementation of inequalities having as an operand std_logic_vector so why the above code statement was accepted and will the above comparison treat A as signed or unsigned number?

Answer (score 3):

-- Copying my comp.lang.vhdl reply to this post.  Sorry some duplicates, but some does not.

All enumerated types and arrays of enumerated types implicitly define the regular ordering relational operators (>, >=, <, <=).  Unfortunately it is not numerically ordered, so the results may not be as expected.  Instead it is dictionary ordered.

First you have to look at the element type, which is std_logic whose base type is std_ulogic.  For an enumerated type, such as std_ulogic, left values are less than right values, hence, for std_ulogic (and std_logic):
'U' < 'X' < '0' < '1' <  'Z' < 'W' < 'L' < 'H' < '-'

For equal length arrays whose element base type is std_ulogic (such as std_logic_vector or std_ulogic_vector) whose values are only 0 or 1, things work out fine:
"1010" > "0101"

Note that dictionary comparisons always compare the left element first.  Hence, for string, something that starts with 'S' is always less than something that starts with 'T' independent of length.  This is great for sorting strings into a dictionary and is the only practical default - if we are going to provide such as thing.

OTOH, this is not so great if you are thinking things are numeric.  For example, if the arrays are not equal length, then the following is true because the leading '1'on the left parameter is > the leading '0' of the right parameter.
"100" > "0111"

Hence, with only "use ieee.std_logic_1164.all", you have potential exposure to bad coding practices that mistakenly think of std_logic_vector as numeric (such as unsigned).

Many will argue, never use std_logic_vector for math and ">" is math.  I generally agree.

So what do I do?  How do I protect my design and design team from this.  First you have to decide a policy and how to implement it.

1) Forbid use of regular ordering relational operators (>, >=, <, <=) with std_logic_vector and enforce it with a lint tool.  However this means you have to buy and require the use of a lint tool.

2) Forbid use of regular ordering relational operators (>, >=, <, <=) with std_logic_vector and enforce it by using the both of the following package references.  Note that this generates errors by referencing two definitions for each of the operators, and hence, when used the expression becomes ambiguous.  Note this may be problematic since numeric_std_unsigned was introduced in 1076-2008 and it may not yet be supported by your synthesis tools.
library ieee ;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all ;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all ;

3) Relax the rules some.  Our biggest concern is design correctness.  Allow std_logic_vector to be interpreted as an unsigned value and either reference numeric_std_unsigned (preferred, but it is VHDL-2008 and may not be implemented by your synthesis tool yet - but if it is not be sure to submit a bug report) or std_logic_unsigned (not preferred - this is an old shareware package that is not an IEEE standard and perhaps does not belong in the IEEE library - OTOH, it is well supported and it plays nice with other packages - such as numeric_std).

The nice result of this is that it also allows comparisons that include integers:
  if A <= 11 then

Note, some suggest that the overloading of ">" and friends in numeric_std_unsigned/std_logic_unsigned is illegal.  This was a very conservative interpretation of 1076 prior to VHDL-2008.  It was fixed for all revisions of VHDL with an ISAC resolution prior to VHDL-2008 that determined that explicitly defined operators always overload implicitly defined operators without creating any ambiguity. I note that even the VHDL FAQ is out of date on this issue.

4) Be formal, but practical.  Never use std_logic_vector.  Only use numeric types, such as unsigned and signed from package ieee.numeric_std.  Types signed and unsigned also support comparisons with integers.

There are probably a few strategies I left out.

Note that VHDL-2008 introduces matching operators which also address this issue by not defining them for types that do not have a numeric interpretation.  These operators are:  ?=, ?/=, ?>, ?>=, ?<, ?<=

Answer (score 2):

"<=" is called a relational operator in VHDL.

It's predefined. See IEEE Std 1076-2008, 9.2.3 Relational operators the table.  It's a predefined operator for any scalar or single dimensional discrete array type.

std_logic_vector qualifies as a single dimensional discrete array type, it's element types discrete, in this case  being enumerated types (std_logic/std_ulogic).  See 5.2 Scalar types, 5.2.1 General, wherein the first paragraph demonstrates an enumerated type is discrete.

And for a simpler answer it's part of the language.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: you *need* to use an extra package: `ieee.numeric_std`

I must assume that you have defined A as a `std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)`.

This data type represents an array of bits. There is *no numeric value* associated with it. Hence, the comparison between A and your bit string literal does not make sense.

If you want to compare the numeric values represented by A, you need to use `unsigned(7 downto 0)` or `signed(7 downto 0)`, preferably from the package `ieee.numeric_std`. This is the accepted good practice to attribute numeric values to arrays of bits.

Technically, you could work around this and define your own "<=" function, but you would just be duplicating code from the VHDL standard IEEE library.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on David's answer slightly: it's predefined for discrete arrays such that, basically, array elements are compared left to right (according to IEEE 1076-2008, 9.2.3), and each scalar array element is compared using its inherent order which, in the case of an enumeration like `std_logic`, is defined by its position (according to 5.2.2.1). `'1'` is "greater than" `'0'` only because its position in the `std_ulogic` declaration is higher (and `'Z'` is "greater than" `'1'` for the same reason).

It should be clear from this that it's not treating the vectors as signed *or* unsigned. It happens to *look* like it's treating the vectors as unsigned **if** they're equal length **and** only contain `'0'` and `'1'`, but you still shouldn't do it.

Comment: Package numeric_std unsigned "<=" resizes arguments to the same length then uses the predefined relational operator via function UNSIGNED_LESS_OR_EQUAL. There's a cartoon from the mid '60s that illustrates, [Is Nothing Sacred?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ePNcd.jpg) by Graham Wilson. Other than different length or natural operands in unsigned operators there is nothing distinct from std_logic_vector. There's a proposal to adopt package std_logic_unsigned, curing the 'shortcoming', it would add a third call going through numeric_std's unsigned operator.

Comment: @DavidKoontz, The intent there is that when an object is a number, then comparisons should indeed do numeric comparisons.  BTW, the proposal you refer to was for 2008 and it resulted in the package numeric_std_unsigned being added to the language.