# VHDL - if < statement not working

Tags: if-statement, integer, signals, vhdl

I am trying to develop an autonomous car. I have a sensor that counts the number of laps of our car's wheels. When the number of laps reaches a specific input number it should change states, but the if statement doesn't seem to be working. Instead of comparing the two numbers, it enters the else statement until the input vueltas is all '1'. If I change the code, and write if (vueltas < 15) it works. But I need the number to be changeable. This is the code, I want the program to stay in the same state until the number of lapsis this imput number. I have already proved that the input number is correct and is 15. The elsif(obst = '1') is in case the car detects an obstacle, but it doesn't matter with this problem.

Note: vueltas = laps in spanish

```
            library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
    use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
    --use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

    entity Circuito is Port (
        clk : in STD_LOGIC;
        ir1 : in STD_LOGIC;
        ir2 : in STD_LOGIC;
        moverCoche : in STD_LOGIC;
        angulo : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
        vMaxCurva : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
        posInicial : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
        vueltasCurva : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
        vueltasRecta : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
        obst : in STD_LOGIC;
        servoOut : out STD_LOGIC;
        motorOut : out STD_LOGIC;
        vueltasLed : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
        vueltasDentroDeCircuito : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
        revolucionesPorSeg : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0));
    end Circuito;

    architecture Behavioral of Circuito is

        component motor_pwm_clk32kHz is Port (
            clk     : in  STD_LOGIC;
            entrada : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
            salida  : out STD_LOGIC);
        end component;

        component servo_pwm_clk32kHz is Port (
            clk   : in  STD_LOGIC;
            pos   : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
            servo : out STD_LOGIC);
        end component;

        component Contador_Vueltas is Port ( 
            out1 : in STD_LOGIC; --Negro: 1  Blanco: 0
            out2 : in STD_LOGIC; --Negro: 1  Blanco: 0
            vueltas : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0);
            rst : in STD_LOGIC;
            clk : in STD_LOGIC);
        end component;

        component revoluciones is Port (
            clk : in STD_LOGIC;
            vueltasDentroDeCircuito : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
            revoluciones : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0));
        end component;

        signal posServo, posMotor: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);

        signal vueltas : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0);
        signal primeraVuelta : STD_LOGIC := '1';
        signal sigReiniciarVueltas : STD_LOGIC;
        signal sigVueltasDentroDeCircuito : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
        signal sigVueltasInicioEstado : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(11 downto 0);
        --signal sigVueltasRecta : unsigned := to_integer(unsigned(vueltasRecta));
        --constant sigVueltasRecta : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0) := "0000011110";
        --constant sigVueltasCurva : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 downto 0) := "0000011110";
        signal flag : STD_LOGIC := '0';

        signal Qt: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        SUBTYPE STATE_TYPE IS STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
        SIGNAL STATE: STATE_TYPE;
        CONSTANT s0 : STATE_TYPE := "0000";
        CONSTANT s1 : STATE_TYPE := "0001";
        CONSTANT s2 : STATE_TYPE := "0010";
        CONSTANT s3 : STATE_TYPE := "0011";
        CONSTANT s4 : STATE_TYPE := "0100";
        CONSTANT s5 : STATE_TYPE := "0101";
        CONSTANT s6 : STATE_TYPE := "0110";
        CONSTANT s7 : STATE_TYPE := "0111";
        CONSTANT s8 : STATE_TYPE := "1000";

    begin

        UUT_Motor: motor_pwm_clk32kHz Port Map (
           clk => clk,
           entrada => posMotor,
           salida => motorOut);

        UUT_Servo: servo_pwm_clk32kHz Port Map (
           clk => clk,
           pos => posServo,
           servo => servoOut);

        UUT_ContadorVueltas: Contador_Vueltas Port Map (
           clk => clk,
           rst => sigReiniciarVueltas,
           vueltas => vueltas,
           out1 => ir1,
           out2 => ir2);

        UUT_Revoluciones: revoluciones Port Map(
           clk => clk,
           vueltasDentroDeCircuito => sigVueltasDentroDeCircuito,
           revoluciones => revolucionesPorSeg
        );

        process(clk, moverCoche)
        begin
            if (moverCoche = '0') then 
                Qt <= s0;
                sigReiniciarVueltas <= '1';
                sigVueltasDentroDeCircuito <= (others => '0');
                posServo <= "10000";
                posMotor <= "10000";
            elsif (clk'event and clk = '1') then 
                case Qt is
                --Quieto
                when s0 =>
                    posServo <= "10000";
                    posMotor <= "10000";
                    sigReiniciarVueltas <= '0';
                    Qt <= s1;
                --Recta1
                when s1 =>
                    sigReiniciarVueltas <= '0';
                    posServo <= "10000";
                    posMotor <= vMaxCurva;    --Min: 10011
                    sigVueltasDentroDeCircuito <= ("00" & vueltas);
                    if (unsigned(vueltas) >= unsigned(vueltasRecta)) then
                        Qt <= s2;
                        sigReiniciarVueltas <= '1';
                    elsif (obst = '1') then
                        Qt <= s8;
                    else
    --                  sigVueltasRecta <= vueltasRecta;          
                        Qt <= s1;                 
                    end if;
                -- Curva1
                when s2 =>
                    sigReiniciarVueltas <= '0';
                    posServo <= angulo;
                    posMotor <= vMaxCurva;
                    sigVueltasDentroDeCircuito <= posInicial + ("00" & vueltas);
                    if (unsigned(vueltas) >= unsigned(vueltasCurva)) then
                        sigReiniciarVueltas <= '1';
                        Qt <= s3;
                    elsif (obst = '1') then
                        Qt <= s8;
                    else 
                        Qt <= s2;
                    end if;
                --Recta2
                when s3 =>
                    sigReiniciarVueltas <= '0';
                    posServo <= "10000";
                    posMotor <= vMaxCurva;    --Min: 10011
                    sigVueltasDentroDeCircuito <= posInicial + vueltasCurva + ("00" & vueltas);
                    if (unsigned(vueltas) >= unsigned(vueltasRecta)) then
                        sigReiniciarVueltas <= '1';
                        Qt <= s4;
                    elsif (obst = '1') then
                        Qt <= s8;
                    else 
                        Qt <= s3;
                    end if;
                --Curva2
                when s4 =>
                    sigReiniciarVueltas <= '0';
                    posServo <= angulo;
                    posMotor <= vMaxCurva;
                    sigVueltasDentroDeCircuito <= posInicial + vueltasCurva + vueltasRecta + ("00" & vueltas);
                    if (unsigned(vueltas) >= unsigned(vueltasCurva)) then
                        sigVueltasDentroDeCircuito <= (others => '0');
                        sigReiniciarVueltas <= '1';
                        Qt <= s4;
                    elsif (obst = '1') then
                        Qt <= s8;
                    else
                        Qt <= s1;
                    end if;

                --Mantener Quieto
                when s5 =>
                    posMotor <= "10000";
                    Qt <= s5;

                when others =>
                    if(obst = '1') then
                        posMotor <= "00000";
                        --sigReiniciarVueltas <= '0';
                        Qt <= s8;
                    else
                        Qt <= s1;
                    end if;
                end case;
                vueltasDentroDeCircuito <= sigVueltasDentroDeCircuito;
                vueltasLed <= vueltasRecta;
            end if;
        end process;
    end Behavioral;
```

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your question doesn't allow your readers to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to perform arithmetic comparison (in this case, `<`) on a `std_logic_vector`, it probably isn't best practice, as it is unknown whether the underlying value is signed or unsigned. If you need to do any arithmetic or comparisons, use `unsigned` or `signed` types from the `numeric_std` package.

A good discussion is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934208/compare-std-logic-vector-to-a-constant-using-std-logic-vector-package-only).

Comment: It still doesn't work. It still does the same. I've changed the code, is there any other changes that I can do?

Comment: @ainhoarru That's not true. Whilst you generally cannot do arithmetic with `std_logic_vector`, you can compare `std_logic_vector` with `<` and similar operators. You should take care if the vectors are different lengths however - you will get strange results.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor I edited my answer to reflect your comment. While you are correct in saying it is possible to perform arithmetic comparison on SLV, I wouldn't have considered it to be a good design practice

Comment: @ainhoarru As user1155120 pointed out, it is hard to reproduce the problem you are having without a MCVE - I'm just speculating at the moment